# Merge PublishSubject after subscription

Tags: java, rx-java

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Integer integer) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("item = " + integer);
        }
    });
    subject.mergeWith(Observable.just(1, 2));
    subject.onNext(3);
    /* 
    expected: 
    item = 1
    item = 2
    item = 3
    but received :
    item = 3
    */
```

I know I can do something like this:

```
PublishSubject.merge(subject, Observable.just(1,2)).subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Integer integer) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("item = " + integer); // emits 1 2 3
        }
    });
```

but the problem is the user has already subscribed to subject.
I couldn't find an elegant way.

**EDIT:** 
As the subjects are both observer and subscriber you can do something like this:

```
final PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Integer integer) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("item = " + integer);
        }
    });
    Observable.just(1,2).subscribe(subject);
    subject.onNext(3);//subscription
    /*
    expected:
    item = 1
    item = 2
    item = 3
    but received :
    item = 1
    item = 2
    */
```

Comment: Isn't this what [`ReplaySubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) is for?

Comment: @jensgram no. The thing is     subject.mergeWith(Observable.just(1, 2));
return a new Observable/Subject to you not merge the Observable into your original one.

Comment: @PhoenixWang Makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. So replacing `Observable.just(1, 2)` with a `ReplaySubject` with items `1` and `2`, then?

Comment: @jensgram as the subscriber subscribe to it already. You don't really need ReplaySubject to replace PublishSubject. It depends on your needs.

Comment: @PhoenixWang I see. Once again, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: The update is because your Observable.just will give your subject onComplete which will terminate the Subject.

Comment: @PhoenixWang I know and this is actually what I wanted basically, the `onNext(3)` was just for the demonstration. your comments pointed me at  right direction, I will accept your answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code into

```
    Subject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    subject.subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Integer integer) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("item = " + integer);
        }
    });
    Observable.just(1,2).doOnNext(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Integer e) throws Exception {
            subject.onNext(e);
        }
    }).subscribe();

    subject.onNext(3);
```

But still. you need to subscribe to this Observable.